# Passing through an iterator as a date

Tags: excel, vba, if-statement

Hi (please excuse the bad formatting and conventions I am not a coder)

I have a `VBA` function that calculates the *time weighted average given a table of dates and values*. The problem is that I cannot pass the iterator through one of the excel functions.

The issue arises in the following line:

```
totalWeighting = totalWeighting + Cells(Application.Match(start_date, dateRange, 1), userCodeColumn)
```

When using `start_date` the function works fine (note that I have a bunch of other code to `Dim variables` which I have excluded). However, when you replace `start_date` with "d", it returns `#value`.

```
Function TimeWeightedAverage(start_date As Date, end_date As Date, user_code) As Double

Dim d As Date
Dim totalWeighting As Double
Dim userCodeColumn As Integer
Dim dateRange As Range
Dim denominator As Integer
Dim startRow As Integer

If Mid(user_code, 3, 1) = 2 Then
    Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    Else
        Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.Range("H:H")
End If

totalWeighting = 0
denominator = WorksheetFunction.NetworkDays(start_date, end_date)
Let userCodeColumn = user_code.Column
Let startRow = Application.Match(start_date, dateRange, 1)

For d = start_date To end_date
    If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(d, 11) < 6 Then
        totalWeighting = totalWeighting + Cells(Application.Match(d, dateRange, 1), userCodeColumn)
    End If
Next



TimeWeightedAverage = totalWeighting / denominator
```

Any thoughts would be greatly appreciated.

Data:

[image: Data]

Comment: What does the error say ?

Comment: On a `For loop` everytime a loop ends will add 1 to the variable, in this case, everytime your weekday is < 6 the procedure will add 1 to d, if it's > 6 then it will add 2, so you will skip a date. Can you elaborate a bit what are you intending to? Maybe there are easier ways to achieve your goal.

Comment: @Mikku - when I used the function in excel, it returns #VALUE

Comment: @Damian its skipping days because I only want to iterate through workdays. The worksheetfunction.weekday part was supposed to do this.

Comment: @dmen so avoid the `Else` you don't need it. On the other hand, try this: `Function TimeWeightedAverage(start_date As Date, end_date As Date) As Double`

Comment: @dmen .... It would be helpful if you can clearly explain in Question in Words what your are trying to get out of this function. I am not able to understand the output you are looking for.

Comment: @Damian removing the else was a good idea. The update didnt change the outcome, however it did let me define start and end dates as dates (as suggested by @Freeflow)

Comment: @dmen post your whole code and a screen of your data, and then the desired output please. This will be easier for all of us...

Comment: @Damian I have posted the whole code with the screenshot. I'm after the time weighted average for each user over a specified period of time. Since this is an excel function, ideally I would be able to put into a cell =TimeWeightedAverage(1/1/19, 31/1/19, (cell JF24))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I think I sorted out your problem.

First of all, a loop like the one you used works with integer/longs/singles/doubles... not dates, so you can't use `d` as a date, because it is not.

On the other hand you were declarin a `startrow` which wasn't being used like `denominator` which was calculating the working days between the 2 dates. Instead, calculate all the days between the 2 dates and loop through all of them increasing 1 day to `startdate`at a time and giving that day to a `Date` variable, your `If`statement will handle if it's a working day or not.

```
Option Explicit
Function TimeWeightedAverage(start_date As Date, end_date As Date, user_code As Range) As Double

    Dim d As Long
    Dim userCodeColumn As Long
    Dim dateRange As Range
    Dim denominator As Long
    Dim CheckDate As Date

    If Mid(user_code, 3, 1) = 2 Then
        Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.Range("A:A")
    Else
        Set dateRange = ActiveSheet.Range("H:H")
    End If

    denominator = DateDiff("d", start_date, end_date)
    Let userCodeColumn = user_code.Column

    For d = 1 To denominator
        If d = 1 Then
            CheckDate = start_date
        Else
            CheckDate = start_date + d
        End If
        If WorksheetFunction.Weekday(CheckDate, 11) < 6 Then
            TimeWeightedAverage = TimeWeightedAverage + ActiveSheet.Cells(Application.Match(CheckDate, dateRange, 1), userCodeColumn)
        End If
    Next

End Function
```